# PDFBox 2.0.8 issue while signing document

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

I'm trying to sign a pdf using this method, but get a document with no size:

```
public static void sign(PDDocument doc) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
        IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    System.out.println("Document pages ? " + doc.getNumberOfPages());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(VisibleSignature.class.getResourceAsStream(CERT_FILE), ALIAS_PASS);
    System.out.println("KeyStore is null ? " + (ks == null));
    VisibleSignature vs = new VisibleSignature(ks, ALIAS_PASS.clone());
    InputStream is = Resource.get(IMAGE_FILE);
    int page = 1;
    vs.setVisibleSignDesigner(doc, 0, 0, -50, is, page);
    is.close();
    vs.setVisibleSignatureProperties("Test", "Test", "Test", 0, page, true);
    PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    System.out.println("Acroform is null ? " + (acroForm == null));
    System.out.println("Acroform getNeedAppearances ? " + (acroForm.getNeedAppearances()));
    if (acroForm != null && acroForm.getNeedAppearances())
        if (acroForm.getFields().isEmpty())
            acroForm.getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.NEED_APPEARANCES);
        else
            System.out.println("/NeedAppearances is set, signature may be ignored by Adobe Reader");
    signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
    signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    if (vs.visibleSignatureProperties != null) {
        vs.visibleSignatureProperties.buildSignature();
        signature.setName(vs.visibleSignatureProperties.getSignerName());
        signature.setLocation(vs.visibleSignatureProperties.getSignerLocation());
        signature.setReason(vs.visibleSignatureProperties.getSignatureReason());
        System.out.println("SignerName " + vs.visibleSignatureProperties.getSignerName());
    }
    signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    vs.signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
    vs.signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(vs.visibleSignatureProperties.getVisibleSignature());
    vs.signatureOptions.setPage(vs.visibleSignatureProperties.getPage() - 1);
    doc.addSignature(signature, vs.signatureOptions);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    doc.saveIncremental(baos);
    doc.close();
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(vs.signatureOptions);
    byte[] content = baos.toByteArray();
    System.out.println("Content length: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + content.length);
}
```

And this is what I get in eclipse log:

> 18:50:25,702  INFO [default task-14] stdout - Document pages ? 1
>
> 18:50:25,740  INFO [default task-14] stdout - KeyStore is null ? false
>
> 18:50:25,779  INFO [default task-14] stdout - Acroform is null ? false
>
> 18:50:25,780  INFO [default task-14] stdout - Acroform getNeedAppearances ? false
>
> 18:50:25,782  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - PDF Structure has been created
>
> 18:50:25,782  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDFTemplateCreator - pdf building has been started
>
> 18:50:25,782  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - ProcSet array has been created
>
> 18:50:25,782  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - PDF page has been created
>
> 18:50:25,783  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - AcroForm has been created
>
> 18:50:25,788  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Signature field has been created
>
> 18:50:25,788  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - PDSignature has been created
>
> 18:50:25,788  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - AcroForm dictionary has been created
>
> 18:50:25,789  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Matrix has been added
>
> 18:50:25,792  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Signature rectangle has been created
>
> 18:50:25,793  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Formatter rectangle has been created
>
> 18:50:25,815  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Visible Signature Image has been created
>
> 18:50:25,815  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Holder form stream has been created
>
> 18:50:25,816  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Holder form resources have been created
>
> 18:50:25,816  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Holder form has been created
>
> 18:50:25,816  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - PDF appearance dictionary has been created
>
> 18:50:25,817  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Stream of another form (inner form - it will be inside holder form) has been created
>
> 18:50:25,817  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Resources of another form (inner form - it will be inside holder form)have been created
>
> 18:50:25,817  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Another form (inner form - it will be inside holder form) has been created
>
> 18:50:25,817  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Now inserted inner form inside holder form
>
> 18:50:25,817  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Created image form stream
>
> 18:50:25,817  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Created image form resources
>
> 18:50:25,818  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Created image form
>
> 18:50:25,818  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Created background layer form
>
> 18:50:25,818  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Inserted ProcSet to PDF
>
> 18:50:25,818  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Injected appearance stream to pdf
>
> 18:50:25,818  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - Visible signature has been created
>
> 18:50:25,819  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSigBuilder - WidgetDictionary has been created
>
> 18:50:25,825 DEBUG [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream - Create InputStream called without data being written before to stream.
>
> 18:50:25,825  INFO [default task-14] org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDFTemplateCreator - stream returning started, size= 21301
>
> 18:50:25,825  INFO [default task-14] stdout - SignerName Test
>
> 18:50:25,857  INFO [default task-14] stdout - Content length: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 0

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: I try to reproduce your issue. What exactly is that `VisibleSignature` class? It seems related to the `CreateVisibleSignature` PDFBox example class but not the same.

Comment: Hi @mkl, the VisibleSignature class is based on CreateVisibleSignature and added the sign method trying to follow the logic from signPDF method located in CreateVisibleSignature class but receiving only a PDDoucument object.

Comment: So copying the original `CreateVisibleSignature` class as `VisibleSignature` and adding your `sign` method should give me what you use?

Comment: I had to do some minor additional changes but then it worked. Cf. my answer on how to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you don't provide the document with a `SignatureInterface` implementation it can use to sign with. Not providing that in this use case makes PDFBox assume you will create the signature externally (for an example look at the original `CreateVisibleSignature` method `sign`). In that case the result is written to the output stream after you set the signature using the `ExternalSigningSupport` method `setSignature`. As you don't do so, your `ByteArrayOutputStream baos` remains empty.

But you do have a `SignatureInterface` instance which you already initialized with certificate and key material: your `VisibleSignature vs`. Thus, I assume your not providing a `SignatureInterface` wasn't done on purpose.

So to provide the `SignatureInterface` you have to use a `PDDocument.addSignature` overload with a `SignatureInterface` parameter. E.g. replacing your call

```
doc.addSignature(signature, vs.signatureOptions);
```

by

```
doc.addSignature(signature, vs, vs.signatureOptions);
```

makes your code working as desired.

Comment: You're right @mkl, adding the interface to addSignature method is the solution for this issue. After making this little big change the result was as expected. Thanks man!